# Listener for new user request in XMPP

Tags: java, xmpp, messaging, smack, asmack

I am trying to setup a chat messanger using xmpp and smack.

I am able to connect,login

```
m_connection.connect();
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
m_connection.login(userName, password);
```

Also I am able to create new users as admin.

```
AccountManager ac = m_connection.getAccountManager();
ac.createAccount(user, password);
```

The only thing that is missing in my cycle is when a client wants to register for the first time. How does the admin user get a notification/request for creating a new user. Is there any listener that I might have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean? Are you saying you want to approve new users in your code? Or that you want to be verified when a new user registers AND comes online? In this case why don't you just listen for when new users come online?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am assuming that When a new client wants to join my xmpp server I first need to create a user for him before he can login.How does the new user send a request to create a new user?

Comment: You just provide them with a registration form and then use the ``createAccount`` method as you have done in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just provide them with a registration form and then use the `createAccount` method as you have done in your example.